# full width inside a div element?

Tags: css

100% width `div` element inside a parent `div` within a `list` seems to not work.

```css
.parent { 
   position : relative;
   width  : 200px;
   height : 200px;
   background-color : #888888;
}

.child {
   width : 100%;
   height : 40px;
   background-color : #555555;
   margin : 1px 0 0 0;
}
li {
 list-style-type : none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <ul>
      <li><div class="child"></div></li>
      <li><div class="child"></div></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set padding-left to 0 for ul. Browser maker add some default styling to some elements like underline to "a" tag. You can use **CSS reset** to remove those styling. For more info [read this article.](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/)

```css
.parent { 
   position : relative;
   width  : 200px;
   height : 200px;
   background-color : #888888;
}

.parent ul { padding-left: 0; }

.child {
   width : 100%;
   height : 40px;
   background-color : #555555;
   margin : 1px 0 0 0;
}
li {
 list-style-type : none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <ul>
      <li><div class="child"></div></li>
      <li><div class="child"></div></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because by default `<li>` has `display: inline`.

You can try to change it to `display: inline-block` or `display: block`, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove default padding from ul element:

```
ul {
padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a browser's "Inspect" feature to see what is causing the li elements to have a width less than expected. After doing so, the ul element appears to consume a width of 81px. This causes the li element to be narrower than expected.

[image]

Reformat the html or make CSS changes to correct this.